# Changing my iCloud account

Tags: iphone, icloud, email

I recently just changed my Apple ID account and I want to change my iCloud account to the same email. I'm thinking of changing it. But, the only problem I have, is whether or not my app and everything on my phone will be deleted and erased when I change my iCloud account. If I change my iCloud account will all of my apps and photos be erased?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the email shouldn’t make a difference. If you delete the account and make a new one backup information could be lost.

From [this Apple Discussion:](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6350341)

> When you delete the account and choose Keep on My iPhone (iPad), contacts, calendars and other synced data will remain on your device.  When you sign in with your new ID to create your new account and choose Merge, these will be uploaded to your new account.  Synced notes and photo stream photos are exceptions to this, which is why you have to take steps to save them prior to deleting the account.

Answer (score 0):

If they are two separate accounts, there is no (easy) way to transfer information between them. If they are the same account, there should be no problem, but you'd need to provide more specifics.